# Echo exec not working tesseract

Tags: php, exec, echo, tesseract

I'm working on using tesseract with PHP and this is my first time using such things as `exec`.

`/usr/local/bin/tesseract /images/hello.png stdout` works perfectly via SSH but nothing happens when I try and run this via PHP;

```
echo exec('/usr/local/bin/tesseract images/hello.png result');
```

But if I try;

```
echo exec('/usr/local/bin/tesseract images/hello.png result 2>&1');
```

Then the page writes `Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.03 with Leptonica` So I feel like I must close.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using the following

```
exec('/usr/local/bin/tesseract /images/hello.png stdout', $msg);
print_r($msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

**Return Values**

The last line from the result of the command. If you need to execute a command and have all the data from the command passed directly back without any interference, use the passthru() function.

To get the output of the executed command, be sure to set and use the output parameter.